Unable to parse the original URL from archive
I am writing you because
I wanted to get the original URL from the archive. I have tried different Python libraries, but I failed to parse the archive link example https://archive.ph/kEOqK
url="https://archive.ph/kEOqK"
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

Error
Connection error occurred: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
Failed to parse the page.

Is there any way to get the original URL from the archive snapshot?
